# Bash - issue with grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've written a small script that is adding a new mount point, unfortunately, when passing the full path as a string to the `grep` function it's getting as input the whole string, only a small part of it.
Here is the relevant parts of the script:

```
DIR_TO_CREATE="/ODV"
MOUNT_POINT="ta1bbn01:/SwDrop/Repository/ODV $DIR_TO_CREATE nfs  rw,hard,async,noatime,nodiratime,intr,bg,tcp,         vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,timeo=4"
FSTAB="/etc/fstab"
isFileContainString () {
result=`grep -Fxc "$2" "$1"`
if [ "$result" -eq 1  ]; then
 echo "fstab already contain this mountpoint"
else
echo "doesn't contain"
fi
}
#MAIN
isFileContainString $FSTAB $MOUNT_POINT
```

Comment: Your description isn't clear - what is the output/outcome of running the script?

Comment: It's always returning 0 which is not correct, I ran the script in debug mode and it seems that evaluation of the grep is getting only part of the string

Comment: Why does an example of a problem with grep need to contain anything more than a single line that calls grep? It's much harder to understand your problem here than it needs to be.

Comment: Because I want to show you the string that I'm passing

Comment: BTW, all-uppercase names are conventionally reserved for environment variables and builtins; regular shell variable names should have at least one lower-case letter. See the fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace.

Comment: Also: `if grep -Fq "$2" "$1"; then ...` would save you the trouble of messing around with `result`, *and* make the `grep` operation more efficient (since it could stop as soon as it sees the first match, rather than needing to read the rest of the file to count).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes!

```
isFileContainString "$FSTAB" "$MOUNT_POINT"
```

Otherwise, `$2` only gets the first word of `$MOUNT_POINT`; subsequent words go into `$3` and on.